# Switching frames with command pattern

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, null, frame, command-pattern

I'm trying to create an intro animation for my flash game, but when it's supposed to go to the second frame of the animation things go wrong.

This is the code (located in the document class) that the start game button in the menu is supposed to execute:

```
gotoAndStop(3);

animationHero1.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, resetWalkAnimation);

var command1:Command =
    new SerialCommand(0, //start animation
        new TweenLiteToCommand(0, animationHero1, 6, { x: 1300, ease:Linear.easeNone } ), //move hero to door
        new ChangeFrameCommand(0, animationHero1, 1), //stop hero animation
        new ParallelCommand(0,
            new PlaySoundCommand(0, new OpenDoorSound), //open the door
            new TweenLiteToCommand(0, animationHero1, 1, { alpha: 0 } ) //fade out hero
        ),
        new ChangeFrameCommand(0.5, this, 4), //next frame
        new TraceCommand(1, this.currentFrame.toString()) //trace current frame
        //new TweenLiteToCommand(0.5, this.animationHero2, 3, { x: 1100, ease:Linear.easeNone } ) //Walk hero across the room
    );
    command1.start();
```

As you can see I'm using the command-pattern. The changeFrameCommand sets "this" to frame number 4. However, when I then trace the currentFrame in the next command the output is "3". This doesn't make any sense as the frame does change to frame 4 when I run the program. The following, now commented out, command then throws a "Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference" as animationHero2 is located in frame 4.

I assume the most likely place of the problem is the changeFrameCommand, so here's the code of that class:

```
    package commands  
    {
import commands.Command;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Stage;

/**
 * ...
 * @author Berry Hermans
 */
public class ChangeFrameCommand extends Command 
{
    private var mc:MovieClip;
    private var frame:int;

    public function ChangeFrameCommand(delay:Number, movieclip:MovieClip, frameNumber:int) 
    {
        super(delay);
        mc = movieclip;
        frame = frameNumber;
    }

    override protected function execute():void
    {
        mc.gotoAndStop(frame);
        complete();
    }

}

    }
```

If anyone could shed some light on this situation, I'd be forever grateful, as my deadline is in 2 days.

As requested, additional code.

SerialCommand class:

```
    package commands {
import flash.events.Event;

public class SerialCommand extends Command {

    private var _commands:Array;

    public function SerialCommand(delay:Number, ...commands) {
        super(delay);
        _commands = commands;
    }

    private var _completeCommandCount:int;

    override final protected function execute():void {

        //set the complete command count to zero
        _completeCommandCount = 0;

        //listen for the complete event of the first subcommand...
        _commands[0].addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onSubcommandComplete);

        //...and start the subcommand
        _commands[0].start();
    }

    private function onSubcommandComplete(e:Event):void {

        //stop listening for the complete event
        Command(e.target).removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onSubcommandComplete);

        //increment the complete command count
        _completeCommandCount++;

        //if all the commands are complete...
        if (_completeCommandCount == _commands.length) {

            //...then this serial command is complete
            complete();
        } else {

            //...otherwise listen for the complete event of the next subcommand...
            _commands[_completeCommandCount].addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onSubcommandComplete);

            //...and start the subcommand
            _commands[_completeCommandCount].start();
        }
    }
}
    }
```

Command class:

```
    package commands {
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.utils.Timer;

public class Command extends EventDispatcher {

    private var _timer:Timer;

    public function Command(delay:Number = 0) {
        _timer = new Timer(int(1000 * delay), 1);
        _timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, onTimerComplete);
    }

    private function onTimerComplete(e:TimerEvent):void {
        execute();
    }

    /**
     * Starts the command.
     * Waits for the timer to complete and calls the execute() method.
     * This method can be used directly as an event listener.
     */
    public final function start(e:Event = null):void {
        _timer.start();
    }

    /**
     * The abstract method for you to override to create your own command.
     */
    protected function execute():void {

    }

    /**
     * Completes the command.
     * Dispatches a complete event.
     * This method can be used directly as an event listener.
     */
    protected final function complete(e:Event = null):void {
        dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.COMPLETE));
    }
}
    }
```

Comment: What resetWalkAnimation do?

Comment: public function resetWalkAnimation(e:Event)
  {
   if (e.target.currentFrame == 8) 
   {
    e.target.gotoAndPlay(2);
   }
  }

Comment: Are the method ChangeFrameCommand.execute executed before executing  new TraceCommand(1, this.currentFrame.toString() ? Can you post SerialCommand.start method? You receive 3 instead of 4 because you pass 3 as parameter " this.currentFrame.toString()"

Comment: ChangeFrameCommand is executed AND completed before TraceCommand is executed. Added the additional code.

Comment: So in your first code: gotoAndStop(3); -step to frame3 than you create new new SerialCommand with new new TraceCommand( in trace command second param is this.currentFrame.toString() then it is evaluated to 3 so if set break point into c-tor of TraceCommand you will see that the command will be creadted with params new TraceCommand( 1,3 ). I,m not sure what execute method of TraceCommand do but I'm almost sure that it will be something like trace(3). In general when you pass use this.currentFrame.toString() it is evaluated to current frame not to the frame after command executing.